# Python Django Create Image Thumbnail During Upload to Amazon S3

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a fully functional Django web form that will upload and store images on Amazon S3.

How can I also create an additional re-sized copies of the same image that is being uploaded and upload them at the same time to Amazon S3?

Ideally, I will have two additional sizes (120x90, 240x180) saved to `/small/` and `/medium/` folders on S3.

For the upload to S3, I'm using `django-storages` and `boto`.

I have looked around and tried different ways, but it seems that all the thumb generating codes floating around are dealing with locally stored files or images that are already stored somewhere online.

My Code:

**models.py**

```
def content_file_name(instance, filename):
    ext = filename.split('.')[-1]
    name = uuid.uuid4().hex
    filename = "%s_%s.%s" % (instance.business_id, name, ext)
    path = 'originals'
    return os.path.join(path, filename)

class Photo(models.Model):
    filename = models.ImageField(upload_to=content_file_name)
    phototitle = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'photo'
```

**views.py**

```
def create(request):

if request.method == 'POST':
    form = UploadForm(request.POST, request.FILES)

    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()

        return ...
else:
    form = UploadForm()

return render(request, 'upload.html', {
    'form': form,
})
```

**form.py**

```
class UplaodForm(ModelForm):

class Meta:
    model = Photo
    fields = "__all__"
```

**settings.py**

```
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = '...'
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = '...'
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = '...'
...

INSTALLED_APPS = (
...
'storages',
```

Comment: have a look at https://github.com/mariocesar/sorl-thumbnail

Comment: You could also do this with a Lambda that triggers on upload to the bucket

Comment: @Max do you have any samples or links for something like that?

Comment: Not off hand, but I'm sure there's a few out there

Comment: Try to use https://github.com/matthewwithanm/django-imagekit it helps your to create thumbnail.

Answer (score 1):

My solution works with any storage, but I tested it for AWS via `django-storage` and boto3. I created a Storage named `ThumbnailStorage` inheriting from the default one (whatever it is) and added the creation of the thumbnails in method _save, so that I have the name and the content. As a last step I declared this `ThumbnailStorage` as the default Storage for the field:

**the storage**

```
import os
import io
from django.core.files.storage import get_storage_class
from PIL import Image


default_storage = get_storage_class()


class ThumbnailStorage(default_storage):

    def _save(self, name, content):

        if hasattr(content, 'content_type'):
            if content.content_type.startswith('image/'):
                self.generate_thumbnails(name, content)
        return super()._save(name, content)

    def generate_thumbnails(self, name, content):

        name1, ext1 = os.path.splitext(name)
        fname, ext = os.path.splitext(content.name)
        format = (ext1 if ext1 != '.jpg' else '.jpeg').strip('.')  

        im = Image.open(content)
        w, h = im.size
        im.thumbnail((120, 90))    # <<< choose your dims
        dest_filename = f'/small/{name}'   # set your name
        fh = default_storage().open(dest_filename, 'wb')
        sfile = io.BytesIO()
        im.save(sfile, format=format)
        fh.write(sfile.getvalue())
        fh.close()
```

**the model**

```
class Photo(models.Model):
    filename = models.ImageField(
        upload_to=content_file_name,
        storage=TumbnailStorage()       # <<< this is where the work is done
    )
    ...
```

Note that jpg is not accepted by Pillow, so you need to translate to jpeg and that I was not able to `im.save(fh)` when the format is jpeg (while it works on png) so I had to add io.StringIO [trick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33612882/saving-a-pillow-file-to-s3-with-boto/37683886#37683886)