# Saving a Pillow file to S3 with boto

Tags: django, amazon-s3, python-imaging-library

I use Amazon S3 as my storage backend via s3boto. I have an Image model with an ImageField. When an image is uploaded via the admin, it is successfully uploaded to S3. What I am now trying to do is to create a thumbnail post-save using Pillow. I have verified that the thumbnail is being created by calling the show() method on it, but for some reason it is not being uploaded to S3. I think the way I am saving it may be wrong - any suggestions would be appreciated please.

**tasks.py**

```
from celery import shared_task
from .models import Image
import os
from django.core.files.storage import default_storage as storage
from PIL import Image as PillowImage

@shared_task
def create_thumbnails(pk):
    try:
        image = Image.objects.get(pk=pk)
    except Image.ObjectDoesNotExist:
        pass
    thumbnail_size = (450,200)
    filename, ext = os.path.splitext(image.image.name)
    try:
        fh = storage.open(image.image.name, 'r')
        im = PillowImage.open(fh)
        im.thumbnail(thumbnail_size)
        im.show() # TEST - This opens the resized image in Preview on my mac
        filename = filename +'_thumbnail' +ext
        new_file = storage.open(filename, 'w')
        im.save(new_file, "PNG")
        new_file.close()
    except IOError as error:
        print("cannot create thumbnail for ", filename, 'error ', error)
```

**Stack**

django 1.85

python 2.7.10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that the solution below is for Python 2.

**models.py**

```
class Image(models.Model):
    caption = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    width = models.IntegerField(default=0, blank=True)
    height = models.IntegerField(default=0, blank=True)
    image = models.ImageField(width_field='width', height_field='height',blank=True)
```

**tasks.py**

```
from celery import shared_task
import os
from django.core.files.storage import default_storage as storage
from django.conf import settings
import mimetypes
import cStringIO
from PIL import Image as PillowImage
import boto
from .models import Image

@shared_task
def create_thumbnails(pk):
    try:
        image = Image.objects.get(pk=pk)
    except Image.ObjectDoesNotExist:
        pass
    try:
        thumbnail_size = (450,200)
        filename, ext = os.path.splitext(image.image.name)
        filename = filename +'_thumbnail' +ext
        existing_file = storage.open(image.image.name, 'r')
        im = PillowImage.open(existing_file)
        im = im.resize(thumbnail_size, PillowImage.ANTIALIAS)
        memory_file = cStringIO.StringIO()
        mime = mimetypes.guess_type(filename)[0]
        plain_ext = mime.split('/')[1]
        im.save(memory_file, plain_ext)
        
        conn  = boto.connect_s3(settings.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, settings.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY)
        bucket = conn.get_bucket( 'yourbucketname', validate=False)
        k = bucket.new_key('media/' +filename)
        k.set_metadata('Content-Type', mime)
        k.set_contents_from_string(memory_file.getvalue())
        k.set_acl("public-read")
        memory_file.close()
    except Exception as error:
        print("cannot create thumbnail for ", filename, 'error ', error)
```

Comment: the blog post doesn't exist anymore, so an important part of your solution is missing. What is `.models.Image`?

Answer (score 10):

This was super helpful and I used it to find a way to write images to s3 from django without using boto directly.

Basically PIL's save() method doesn't work with s3, but the default_storage.write() method does. The key was to use the default_storage.write() method to write binary data directly from the StringIO memory file like this:

```
file_to_write.write(memory_file.getvalue())
```

Here's the code I ran in the django shell (python manage.py shell) to test this:

```
>>> from django.core.files.storage import default_storage as storage
>>> from PIL import Image
>>> import StringIO
>>> i = storage.open('ImageToCreate.jpg','w+')
>>> m = storage.open('ImageAlreadyOnS3.jpg','r')
>>> im = Image.open(m)
>>> im = im.resize((640,360),3)
>>> sfile = StringIO.StringIO() #cStringIO works too
>>> im.save(sfile, format="JPEG")
>>> i.write(sfile.getvalue())
>>> i.close()
>>> m.close()
```

It works in my views.py as well.

I found it useful since it works both on the remote s3 storage and my local development environment (a folder on my laptop).

Comment: This is one of the most useful answers I have seen around here, can't believe I am the first to upvote it

Answer (score 4):

Note that with Python3, you might want to use BytesIO:

```
from io import BytesIO

# 'image' is a PIL image object.

imageBuffer = BytesIO()
image.save(imageBuffer, format=imageType)

imageFile = default_storage.open(imageFileName, 'wb')
imageFile.write(imageBuffer.getvalue())
imageFile.flush()
imageFile.close()
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue.

```
default_storage.write() # It didn't work. it was not saving anything to s3
```

The @RunLoop answer was quite complicated and different then what I wanted to do with Django so, I did this and it worked.

```
    import StringIO
    from PIL import Image
```

First, read the file uploaded

```
    image = request.FILES['image'].read()  #atleast in my case
```

create a file like object so that we can use Image to read it

```
    image_file = StringIO.StringIO(image)
    thumbnail_image = Image.open(image_file)
```

resize the image to desired size

```
    resized_thumbnail_image = thumbnail_image.resize((200, 200), Image.ANTIALIAS)
```

create another file like object or inmemory file, so that we can write the Image instance to it and get string value - which should be passed to default storage

```
    resized_thumbnail_image_file = StringIO.StringIO()
    resized_thumbnail_image.save(resized_thumbnail_image_file, 'JPEG',quality=90)

    default_storage.save(save_path, ContentFile(resized_thumbnail_image_file.getvalue()))
```

My first detailed answer, hope it helps.

**Stack:
python 2.7
Django 1.8**

Comment: this should. be the accepted answer. To update it to python 3 use `from io import BytesIO` instead of `StringIO`. or you will fall in this problem - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50797043/string-argument-expected-got-bytes-in-buffer-write

Answer (score 0):

A slightly more understandable, workable example than [rotten](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54185891/1577947)'s answer

```
from io import BytesIO
from PIL import Image
from django.core.files.base import ContentFile
from django.core.files.storage import default_storage
from django.contrib.staticfiles.storage import staticfiles_storage

img = Image.new('RGB', (1920, 1080), color = 'red') # <-- use this
#img = Image.open(r'C:\Users\you\Pictures\profile.jpg') # <-- or a file on your computer

buffer = BytesIO()
img.save(buffer, format='JPEG')

fp = '{path}{name}'.format(path='adminz/profile/', name='default.jpg')
f = default_storage.open(fp, 'wb')
f.write(buffer.getvalue())
f.close()
```

I'm using Django Storages which is why I needed to figure this out. Extra unused imports I included because you'll often find a reason to know them when dealing with this subject.

Another example of something I used in a project:

```
image = Image.open(photo) # <- open
cropped_image = image.crop((x, y, w + x, h + y)) # <- do something
with BytesIO() as f:
    cropped_image.save(f, format=settings.THUMBNAIL_FORMAT, quality=95) # <- save to buffer
    img = f.getvalue()

post.featured_image.save(photo.name,
                         content=ContentFile(img))
```