# Upload Thumbnail Image to S3 using Boto3

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto3, python-imaging-library, falconframework

I'm using the Falcon framework and [Pillow](http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/4.2.x/index.html) to upload a profile picture of a contact to S3, then resizing that picture for a thumbnail, and then uploading that thumbnail.

I've looked at other answers but some of them require having [bucket write access activated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37683886/6365534) and some use django's `default_storage` feature which I don't have available.

```
client = boto3.client('s3',
    aws_access_key_id=os.environ.get('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
    aws_secret_access_key=os.environ.get('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY')
)


class UploadResource(object):

    def on_post(self, req, res):
        #gathering file from SPA
        contact_id = req.get_param('id')
        filename = req.get_param('file').filename
        file = req.get_param('file').file
        salt = ''.join(chr(random.randint(97, 122)) for i in range(20))
        filename = salt + '-' + filename
        filename_thumb = salt + '-thumb-' + filename

        #uploading normal sized image
        client.upload_fileobj(file, 'contacts-cloud-images', filename)  

        #pull down image again and resize
        img = Image.open(requests.get(image_url, stream=True).raw)
        img.thumbnail((50,50))
        print(img.format, img.size)

        #save it to BytesIO container
        io = BytesIO()
        img.save(io, img.format)

        #upload value of BytesIO container
--->    client.upload_fileobj(io.getvalue(), 'contacts-cloud-images', filename_thumb)
```

I get the following error from the line with the arrow (`---->`):

`ValueError: Fileobj must implement read`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error means `client.upload_fileobj` is expecting a file-like object that implements a `read` method, but you're passing it the content of the file-like object (`io.getvalue()`) instead of the file-like object itself (`io`)

This is a link to the documentation of [upload_fileobj](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.upload_fileobj)

**Important non-related note**: An important thing to note is you're naming the variable that holds your buffer `io`. `io` is also the name of a module of the standard library, and you're overwriting it. That should be an absolute no-no. Despite the local scope of your variable, I recommend you rename it to something meaninful, like `file_content` or `image_content`.

Comment: It's now saying on S3 that the uploaded file is `0B`. I'm not sure what could have happened that caused the file to contain no data in the above code. I did end up uploading the `io` object instead of using the `getvalue()` method. (I did rename it as well, thank you for that.)

Comment: I'd verify that the line `print(img.format, img.size)` is printing a non-zero value for size. To clarify, boto3 doesn't _upload the file-like object_, it uploads the content of the file, but it's built in such a way that you need to pass the file-like object to it

Comment: I'll also point out that I don't see image_url defined anywhere. However, it's far fetched to think that's the cause of the problem, since requests.get would raise an error if image_url didn't contain a valid url, and Image.open would raise an error if the body of the request didn't contain a valid image.

Comment: Thank you, it turns out that I had to call `.seek(0)` on the file-like object to _rewind_ it to the beginning.