# string argument expected, got 'bytes' in buffer.write

Tags: python, file

I have this:

```
from io import StringIO
buffer = StringIO()

latest_file = 'C:\\Users\\miguel.santos\\Desktop\\meo_snapshots\\Snapshot_14.jpg'

buffer.write(open(latest_file,'rb').read())

TypeError: string argument expected, got 'bytes'
```

Any ideas on how to solve?

Comment: Don't use `rb` as it gives you `bytes` object, use `r`.

Comment: @zipa Probably, more consistent would be to not use `StringIO` for binary data (it's hard to use `'r'` to read a JPEG file I assume.)

Answer (score 47, accepted):

`io.StringIO` is for unicode text, its counterpart for bytes is `io.BytesIO`. As your undelying file is a binary jpg, you really should use the latter:

```
from io import BytesIO
buffer = BytesIO()

latest_file = 'C:\\Users\\miguel.santos\\Desktop\\meo_snapshots\\Snapshot_14.jpg'

buffer.write(open(latest_file,'rb').read())
```

Comment: Indeed the io.BytesIO in py3 corresponds to cStringIO.StringIO in py2 better.